# I want to split data from serial comm and deliver it to table

Tags: java, database, split, serial-communication

I want to split data serial with this format

```
<STX> data1<FS> Data2<FS> Data3<FS> ...Data_n<FS>Checksum<ETX>
```

where

- STX is 0x02 in hex
- FS  is 0x1C in hex
- ETX is 0x03 in Hex

then I need to send it to database table

I use RXTX library and get result by byte value.

Can someone help and share with me how to do that ?

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you have any code, dude ?

Answer (score 0):

i have get result with ugly ways i think but the real problem is i just want to input data array from  array [2] until length -2. for now (i made 60 static array length) but the data will always be dynamic length in array. is there a way to solve this. i heard about list data type but it's even more harder i think.

```
public Constructor(GUI window)
    {
        this.dump = new String[60];
        this.window = window;
    }
int i = 0; String[] dump; boolean begin = false,first=true;
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
            {
                try
                    {
                        byte singleData = (byte)input.read();

                       if (singleData == 2){
                           begin =true; i=0; 
                       }
                       if (singleData == 3){
                           begin = false; writeData(); 
                       }
                       if (begin == true){
                            if (singleData != 28 && singleData!=2 ){
                                if(dump[i]!=null && first==false){
                                dump[i]=dump[i]+ new String(new byte[] {singleData});                       
                                }


                                if(dump[i]==null){
                                    dump[i]=new String(new byte[] {singleData});
                                    first=false;
                                }
                            }

                            if (singleData==28){
                                    System.out.println(dump[i] + "  No." + i );
                                    first=true;
                                    i++;      
                            }
                       }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        logText = "Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() + ")";
                        window.txtLog.setForeground(Color.red);
                        window.txtLog.append(logText + "\n");
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: here's the result                                                                                                      R  No.0
*  No.1
SUKIMAN  No.2
46/38  No.3
1  No.4
null  No.5
0  No.6
363812270115  No.7
1  No.8
1  No.9
4  No.10
TGL  No.11
197  No.12
mg/dl  No.13
null  No.14
ALDL  No.15
179  No.16
mg/dl  No.17
null  No.18
URCA  No.19
6.0  No.20
mg/dl  No.21
null  No.22
GLUC  No.23
179  No.24
mg/dl  No.25
null  No.26
87  No.27